# How to insert new element to 'this' child element Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I have nested for loop. The first is for getting questions and answer from XML file, and the inner loop is to add sub questions that belong to the head question... 
my code:

```
  for (var i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        var question = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('question').text();
        var sizeQ = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('question_down').size();
        var answer = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('answer').text
        $('.faq_row').append(" <div class='faq_details'> <li class='faq_quest' > <a class='faq_row_question'>" + question +
            "<div class='faq_triangle_down'> </div></a> <div class='faq_inside_question'> <p class='faq_answer'>" + answer + "</p> <div class='faq_sub_questions'> </div> </div> </li> </div> <br>"); //here i get question and answer for the question

        for (var j = 0; j < sizeQ; j++) {
            var subquestion = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('question_down').eq(j).text();
            $('.faq_sub_questions').append("<a class = 'faq_sub_question_link'>" + subquestion + "</a> <br class='faq_br'>"); // here i get all sub questions

        }
    }
```

My problem is that the all sub questions write to the same class "faq_sub_questions", in the first question I see all the sub questions that in the XML file,
i want to add for each question is own sub questions...
any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to store your `faq_details` element in variable, Then use this variable to targer the current row `faq_sub_questions` div using `find` method and finally append your divs links `faq_sub_question_link`  :

```
//Store your faq_details in variable
var faq_details = $(" <div class='faq_details'> <li c.....");
$('.faq_row').append( faq_details );

//Then use this variable to targer the current row
faq_details.find('.faq_sub_questions').append("<a class = 'faq_sub_question_link'>...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and then reference a new parent element each time like so:

```
  for (var i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        var question = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('question').text();
        var sizeQ = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('question_down').size();
        var answer = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('answer').text

        // here define `parenter` variable
        var parenter = $(" <div class='faq_details'> <li class='faq_quest' > <a class='faq_row_question'>" + question +
            "<div class='faq_triangle_down'> </div></a> <div class='faq_inside_question'> <p class='faq_answer'>" + answer + "</p> <div class='faq_sub_questions'> </div> </div> </li> </div> <br>");

        // here append using the new variable name
        $('.faq_row').append( parenter ); //here i get question and answer for the question

        for (var j = 0; j < sizeQ; j++) {
            var subquestion = xml.find('row').eq(i).find('question_down').eq(j).text();
            // here again append to new parent variable instead
            parenter.children(".faq_sub_questions").append("<a class = 'faq_sub_question_link'>" + subquestion + "</a> <br class='faq_br'>"); // here i get all sub questions

        }
    }
```